# Is it possible retrive hourly data from daily weather data?

Tags: python, data, data-analysis, interpolation

I'm a beginner, so sorry if my question could be basic. Reading on internet I've found example written in python that makes the reverse of my questions (covert from daily to monthly).
My problem is that. I've develop an ANN which requires hourly weather data (temperature, humidity, precipitation).
However I've only daily weather data for each day. (averange temperature, averange humidity, averange precipitation).
Is it possible retrieve from daily data the hourly data in python? if yes, how?which libraries?

Daily data

```
Data         station      avg Temperture     avg Humidity   avg rainfall
18/07/2019   Los Angeles  23                 50             0.0
```

I'd like to have that

```
Data         station       Hour   avg Temperture     avg Humidity   avg rainfall
18/07/2019   Los Angeles  0:00       23                 50             0.0
18/07/2019   Los Angeles  1:00       22                 45             0.0
18/07/2019   Los Angeles  2:00       20                 42             0.0
... and so on since have 24 intervals for each day
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but it looks like you're trying to magically obtain data which doesn't exist: a dataset with daily records can be converted to monthly records because it contains **more** than the target data, so it's a matter of removing or averaging the existing records. The opposite process could only be some kind of interpolation, it would not be equivalent to real daily records.

Comment: Sorry, I written monthly instead daily. I corrected

Comment: Adding interpolated data is very unlikely to improve the model afaik, but ok.